# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a<\frac1a<b<\frac1b$ then $a<-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a<\frac1a<b<\frac1b$ then $a<-1$

I'm stuck on this one. Where does one begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases.  Either $a>0$ or $a<0$. ($a$ must be nonzero since the problem refers to $1/a$)

case 1) $a>0\Rightarrow a<\frac{1}{a} \Rightarrow a^2 < 1\Rightarrow 0<a<1$

Consider what happens with the addition of $b$ into the mix.

Since $0<a<\frac{1}{a}<b<\frac{1}{b}$, you have that $0<a<b$ and $b$ is positive.  By a similar argument as used for $a$, you get that $0<b<1$

Then $0<a<\frac{1}{a}<b<1$, but that is a contradiction since for $0<a<1$ you have $\frac{1}{a}>1$.  Therefore it cannot be that $a>0$.

case 2) $a<0\Rightarrow a<\frac{1}{a} \Rightarrow a^2>1 \Rightarrow a<-1$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly , to show that $a<0$.

If not , $a>0$, from the inequation , $b>a>0 \Rightarrow ab>0$

However, $\frac {1}{a} < \frac {1}{b} \Rightarrow ab\frac {1}{a}  < ab \frac {1}{b}\Rightarrow b<a$ It contradicts $a<b$.

Thus $a<0$ , from $ a<\frac {1}{a} \Rightarrow 1>\frac {1}{a^2} \Rightarrow |a|>1\Rightarrow a<-1$